# Is there a way to load an .Rdata file into R shiny without any input object?

Tags: file-upload, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

I've seen many questions about uploading .Rdata files into R shiny but they all include some kind of input object. Is there a way to upload it in the global enviroment and the use it inside the app to create new objects? Gotta say that this .Rdata file is an outcome of another shiny app.
This is what I've tried:

```
# --------------------------------------- Global --------------------------------------- #

# Set working directory -> Ctrl+Shift+H & Open the app folder
setwd("~/Programación en R/Shiny app/Final dashboard app")

# --------------------- Initialize program --------------------- #

# Print in console: global script is beginning to run
print("global.R")

# Allow specific errors to be displayed on screen, instead of displaying a generic error
options(shiny.sanitize.errors = FALSE)

# Load LDA model outcome, topic names & raw data
load("LDA_output.2019-12-28.RData")

#--------------------------------------- User Interface ---------------------------------------#

# Tell user ui script is beginning to run
print("ui.R")

ui <- fluidPage( 
  theme = shinytheme("cerulean"), 

    DT::dataTableOutput("lili")

) #fluidPage

#--------------------------------------- Server ---------------------------------------#

 server <- function(input, output, session) {

 mod <- reactive({get(load("LDA_output.2019-12-28.RData"))})
 print(mod())
 output$lili <- DT::renderDataTable({
   DT::datatable(as.data.frame(mod()[[1]][3])) #list inside that list

 })
 }
 shinyApp(ui, server)
```

And this is the error that comes out of it:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6282
Warning: Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext: Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
  58: stop
  57: .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext
  56: getCurrentContext
  55: .dependents$register
  54: mod
  52: server [#4]
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
```

---

This is the server function I'm using for last,

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
observe({
print(typeof(mod))})
output$lili <- DT::renderDataTable({
  DT::datatable(as.data.frame(mod[[2]]))

})
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

But still something is wrong:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6282
[1] "list"
Warning: Error in checkName: Must use single string to index into reactivevalues
  [No stack trace available]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is due to:

```
print(mod())
```

`mod()` is reactive and needs to be in a reactive context, like `observe`. But I'm not sure there's any reason to make your data, loaded from .Rdata, reactive.  Your first 'load` should make the objects available for you.

Comment: I just don't know. It doesn't work either when I take off the load section from the server function and just leave the output one; it says that it can't find the mod function when that's the real name on loaded data.

Comment: Start a new R session, and only load that .Rdata file. THen run `ls()`. The object names R prints out are all those loaded from the file. All those objects should be usable in your hi and server functions, if you load at the top of your script.

Comment: This is the outcome: `> load("LDA_output.2019-12-28.RData")
> ls()
[1] "mod"` but still says there is no mod function when I try to use it later on! :( mod is a list with another list [1], a data frame [2] and another data frame [3] as objects, think that might have something to do with it?

Comment: Are you still calling it as a function, like `mod()`? If it’s a list, Just call `mod`.

Comment: It says `Warning: Error in [.reactivevalues: Single-bracket indexing of reactivevalues object is not allowed.
  [No stack trace available]` when I use `DT::datatable(as.data.frame(mod[2]))` but says  `<ReactiveValues> 
  Values:     
  Readonly:  FALSE 
Warning: Error in checkName: Must use single string to index into reactivevalues
  [No stack trace available]` when `mod[[2]]`

Comment: At this point, `mod` should not be reactive. This line should still be in your script, at the top, `load("LDA_output.2019-12-28.RData")`. This line should be removed in your server function: `mod <- reactive({get(load("LDA_output.2019-12-28.RData"))})`

Comment: I edited my question at the end, it does print that mod is a list type in the console with those lines. I'm still loading it on my global enviroment, also tried loading it inside the server function again, but it keeps on saying this: `Error in checkName: Must use single string to index into reactivevalues` anyway.

Comment: Is your mod object from your `.Rdata` file a `reactiveValues` list? Change `typeof(mod)` to `class(mod)` to see.  You want it to just be 'list'

Comment: class says it's `[1] "reactivevalues"'.

Comment: So that means whenever you saved your original `mod` object is was a `reactiveValues` object.   You want that to just be a normal list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205247/discussion-between-melania-cb-and-smokeyshakers).